# "Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined" OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working with 3 different files:

- [root]/client/js/welcome.js
- [root]/client/js/ups.js
- [root]/client/js/main.js (I also renamed it xxx.last.js)

Code:

```
//welcome.js
function Welcome(){
    console.log("main");
}

Welcome.prototype.constructor = Welcome;


Welcome.prototype.displayPage = function(page){
    var jQ_page = $("#" + page);
    var title = jQ_page.attr("data-tile");
    $("#main").css("display", "none");
    jQ_page.css("display", "block");
    document.title = title;
};

//ups.js
function Ups(){
    this.query = {};
    this.creteria = {sort: {JB_owner: 0}, limit: 500, skip: 0, fields: {ClusterId: 0}};
    console.log("UPS");
}

Ups.prototype.constructor = Ups;

Meteor.startup(function() {
    var mainObj = new Welcome();        
    var UpsObj = new Ups();

    $(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    ...
    ...   
    });
});
```

Welcome and Ups are undefined and I don't understand why, all three files are being loaded and according [meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) that should works but it doesn't, any hint or help?

thanks!

Comment: `Welcome.prototype.constructor = Welcome;` I'm don't usually extend the prototypes but that line seems like you are assigning something to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing)

> When declaring functions, keep in mind that function x () {} is just shorthard for var x = function () {} in JavaScript.

Which means that you are scoping your functions to the file, rather than the app. Try this instead.

```
Welcome = function () {
    console.log("main");
};

Ups = function () {
    this.query = {};
    this.creteria = {sort: {JB_owner: 0}, limit: 500, skip: 0, fields: {ClusterId: 0}};
    console.log("UPS");
};
```

Comment: I don't think so. The only thing that's changed is the scope of the constructor functions.